# I must run ./odoo.py as root instead of just having odoo service started

Tags: debian, software-installation, services

I just fresh-installed [Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/) 9.0 onto a fresh-installed Debian 8.3.

I am having a strange problem, which I don't know, how to solve because I don't really understand it.

Odoo only works when I run `sudo service odoo stop` and then `sudo /usr/bin/odoo.py`.

When the service is started, then on http://127.0.0.1:8069/ it says:

> 500 Internal Server Error

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check Apache or your webserver's error logs.

As a side note, I recommend using [Bitnami Odoo Stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/odoo), it handles Odoo's dependencies, bugs, relatively complex configuration, and unclear requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Read the [manual](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/setup/install.html#setup-install-packaged). Most likely:

> After installation you will need to create a postgres user: by default the only user is postgres, and Odoo forbids connecting as postgres.